# EF multiple select queries in atomic transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Probably using the wrong wording here though I have a question about transactions in EF. Most answers and questions I stumble upon claim you should just let default EF handle transactions.

In my case I need to query the database (at least) three times for certain data.
It is important that this data comes from the same state, it will be inserted in one transaction using saveChanges in a different call/thread.

So since they're multiple tables and some data comes in a list, some in a single object/row I need multiple select statements.

My idea is to use a transaction during this read. My expectation is that either the data retrieved can be already out of date though this is fine; or that during the transaction an insert will cause the transaction to rollback.

My Question, is my assumption correct? Secondly, is this the way to go?

For our normal simple queries, they will get kicked out if a different thread tries to insert data. So this is Optimistic-Read I believe.

Could someone fill me in here?

Comment: It depends on transaction isolation level of your transaction. Though this "during the transaction an insert will cause the transaction to rollback" will not ever happen (and there is nothing to rollback actually - you only read, not modify data).

Comment: Exception will be thrown only if transaction will timeout (because for example your insert is very very long and locked data you are going to select). Anyway - wrap your selects in transaction and choose appropriate isolation level (repeatable read should do I think). And try to complete transaction as fast as possible, because it will block your inserts (and inserts will block selects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can use Transactions with EF, although it is less than straightforward and frequently unneccessary.

You need to use the [`dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.begintransaction(v=vs.113).aspx) method to kick it off. This method takes an [`IsolationLevel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.isolationlevel(v=vs.113).aspx) parameter which determines locking, dirty reads etc.

For more info on Isolation Levels refer to the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql)

Comment: Yeah - I am totally in the dark about Chaos Isolation...have used most of the others at some point